# How the relevant part of the report sent to relevant party using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Sales report should be sent to all the relevant department heads. Ex: Plastic department should
get only the plastic department sales while garment department should receive only its
department data. How to accomplish this requirement using SSRS?

Comment: The easiest approach would be to use the _Data-Driven subscriptions_ feature.  I believe this requires SQL Server Enterprise though.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would to, and it is an easy approach. Plus, no Enterprise Edition needed for this.

Add a department parameter to the report, and make sure the data uses the parameter value to filter the results, whether that is done at the dataset level (filtering the data at the database level in the `WHERE` clause), or using the filter in a Tablix (in the tablix properties, on the Filter page).

[Adding Parameters to a Report (SSRS)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432(v=sql.105).aspx)

The parameter filter would apply to the whole report, unless you use the value to show/hide parts of the report. With report subscriptions, you get the whole report, not just a part. Your question title makes me think you only want a part of the report to be delivered, and that is not possible.

Then, when you set up a report subscription, choose the appropriate department depending on the recipients.

[How to: Subscribe to a Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157386(v=sql.105).aspx)

This way, when a another department comes along that wants the report, then you can just create a new subscription, and you're done.